# Extracting sample rate from spectrogram

Tags: numpy, spectrogram, sample-rate

I have a set of spectrograms as numpy arrays. Is there any way that I could find their sample rates? I don't have any other information, for example the original sound files.

Comment: could you add the code please?

Comment: @kmario23 what code would that be? ;-) Qubix if you really know nothing at all I don't see how you could make any inference. Don't you at least know the axes, for example the frequency range?

Comment: You could try reconverting to wav files using common sampling rates. If the sounds are something recognizable you might be able to "tell" which is the correct rate.

Comment: @PaulPanzer I meant the code that OP has tried already for this.

Comment: @kmario23 just joshing. You see, given the fundamental difficulty the OP is describing, how can they be expected to have written any code at all? I mean, you need at least an idea, right?

Comment: @PaulPanzer you're right., haha

Comment: In the meantime I managed to get my hands on the original wav files. This solves the problem for me, but this question should probably remain open, since there are people who might really not have the sound files.